# C# How do I click a button by hitting Enter whilst textbox has focus?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working with a WinForm app in C#, after I type something in a textbox I want to hit the Enter key but the textbox still has focus (flashing cursor is still in textbox), how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 90):

The simple option is just to set the forms's AcceptButton to the button you want pressed (usually "OK" etc):

```
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    Button btn = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };
    btn.Click += delegate { Debug.WriteLine("Submit: " + tb.Text); };
    Application.Run(new Form { AcceptButton = btn, Controls = { tb, btn } });
```

If this isn't an option, you can look at the KeyDown event etc, but that is more work...

```
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    Button btn = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom };
    btn.Click += delegate { Debug.WriteLine("Submit: " + tb.Text); };
    tb.KeyDown += (sender,args) => {
        if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            btn.PerformClick();
        }
    };
    Application.Run(new Form { Controls = { tb, btn } });
```

Answer (score 38):

The usual way to do this is to set the `Form`'s `AcceptButton` to the button you want "clicked".  You can do this either in the VS designer or in code and the `AcceptButton` can be changed at any time.

This may or may not be applicable to your situation, but I have used this in conjunction with `GotFocus` events for different `TextBox`es on my form to enable different behavior based on where the user hit Enter.  For example:

```
void TextBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AcceptButton = ProcessTextBox1;
}

void TextBox2_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.AcceptButton = ProcessTextBox2;
}
```

One thing to be careful of when using this method is that you don't leave the `AcceptButton` set to `ProcessTextBox1` when `TextBox3` becomes focused.  I would recommend using either the `LostFocus` event on the `TextBox`es that set the `AcceptButton`, or create a `GotFocus` method that all of the controls that don't use a specific `AcceptButton` call.

Answer (score 36):

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
         button.PerformClick();
         // these last two lines will stop the beep sound
         e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
         e.Handled = true;
     }
}
```

Bind this KeyDown event to the textbox, then when ever you press a key, this event will be fired. Inside the event we check whether user has pressed "Enter key", if so, you can perform you action

Comment: Could You add some explanation?

Comment: I prefer this answer, it is by far the simplest.

Comment: Why not just use *Accept Button*?

Answer (score 11):

I came across this whilst looking for the same thing myself, and what I note is that none of the listed answers actually provide a solution when you don't want to click the 'AcceptButton' on a Form when hitting enter.

A simple use-case would be a text search box on a screen where pressing enter should 'click' the 'Search' button, not execute the Form's AcceptButton behaviour.

This little snippet will do the trick;

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 13)
    {
        if (!textBox.AcceptsReturn)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, this code is part of a custom UserControl derived from TextBox, and the control has a 'ClickThisButtonOnEnter' property. But the above is a more general solution.

Comment: Additionally, you can set `e.Handled` to `true` to avoid the beep.

Comment: Wow, clean and easy, I like it!

Answer (score 9):

Simply set form "**Accept Button**" Property to button that you want to hit by Enter key.
Or in load event write `this.acceptbutton = btnName;`

Comment: perfect solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Most beginner friendly solution is:

1. In your Designer, click on the text field you want this to happen. 
   At the properties Window (default: bottom-right) click on the thunderbolt (Events). This icon is next to the alphabetical sort icon and the properties icon.
2. Scroll down to `keyDown`. Click on the Dropdown field right to it. You'll notice there's nothing in there so simply press enter. Visual Studio will write you the following code:

   ```
   private void yourNameOfTextbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {

   }
   ```
3. Then simply paste this between the brackets:

   ```
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
        yourNameOfButton.PerformClick();
   }
   ```

This will act as you would have clicked it.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2017, using c#, just add the AcceptButton attribute to your button, in my example "btnLogIn":

```
this.btnLogIn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
//....other settings
this.AcceptButton = this.btnLogIn;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can just use this simple 2 liner code :)

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            button1.PerformClick();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the Form's constructor:

```
this.textboxName.KeyDown += (sender, args) => {
    if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
        buttonName.PerformClick();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The TextBox wasn't receiving the enter key at all in my situation.  The first thing I tried was changing the enter key into an input key, but I was still getting the system beep when enter was pressed.  So, I subclassed and overrode the ProcessDialogKey() method and sent my own event that I could bind the click handler to.

```
public class EnterTextBox : TextBox
{
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable]
    public event EventHandler EnterKeyPressed;

    protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            EnterKeyPressed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can trap it on the keyup event http://www.itjungles.com/dotnet/c-how-to-easily-detect-enter-key-in-textbox-and-execute-a-method

Answer (score 0):

This is very much valid for WinForms. However, in WPF you need to do things differently, and it is easer.
Set the **IsDefault** property of the **Button** relevant to this text-area as true.

Once you are done capturing the enter key, do not forget to toggle the properties accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        button1_Click(textBox1.Focus(),e);
    }  
}
```

Comment: a  bit of explanation would be good

Comment: I have this option working together with the button

Comment: Please don't provide code-only answers. It's unclear how or why (or even if) this solves the given problem. It's helpful to explain why the problem was happening in the first place and specifically how this solves it. Answers like this aren't very useful to people other than the OP because with no explanation, it's harder to know if this solution would work in this situation or how to apply it to their situation. It's not even really helpful to the OP in the sense that they don't learn anything other than how to copy and paste your code. This doesn't teach them how to solve it in the future.