# That enter will replace button_click

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# How do I click a button by hitting Enter whilst textbox has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299086/c-how-do-i-click-a-button-by-hitting-enter-whilst-textbox-has-focus)

I want when I press enter it will resemble clicking button.
I have a textbox used a search box when the button is Levahtim search begins. I want that clicking the enter do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `TextBox.KeyDown` event adding the following:

```
if (args.KeyCode == Keys.Return)        
{            
    button.PerformClick();        
}
```

---

Refer to:

[Control.KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)

[Button.PerformClick Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx)

Comment: don't do this. Use AcceptButton instead like the accepted answer in the dupe

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thank you. That's only applicable if I have a dialog .. right ?

Answer (score 0):

@sharon: I believe that you can find the answer here:

[C# How do I click a button by hitting Enter whilst textbox has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299086/c-how-do-i-click-a-button-by-hitting-enter-whilst-textbox-has-focus)