# C# Press Enter to Press Button

Tags: c#

I have written the following code, which all works fine except that hitting the Enter key still doesn't click he Login button. HELP!

```
int failedAttempts;

private void uiPasswordTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        uiLoginButton.PerformClick();
    }
}

private void uiLoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (uiPasswordTextBox.Text == "alacaZam")
    {
        uiPasswordTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        this.uiLogOffButton.Enabled = true;
        this.uiMarkEntryNameTextBox.Enabled = true;
        this.uiMarkEntryClassTestTextBox.Enabled = true;
        this.uiMarkEntryConicalTextBox.Enabled = true;
        this.uiMarkEntryDestructiveTextBox.Enabled = true;
        this.uiStoreMarksButton.Enabled = true;
        this.uiShowMarksAZButton.Enabled = true;
        this.uiShowMarks100_0Button.Enabled = true;
    }
    else if (failedAttempts <= 1)
    {
        failedAttempts++;
        MessageBox.Show("You are permitted 3 attempts. " + (3 - failedAttempts) + " attempt/s remaining.", "Incorrect Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    else if (failedAttempts == 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Access Denied", "Incorrect Password. Entered 3 Times", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling uiLoginButton_Click(null,null) on Enter press

Comment: Check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299086/c-sharp-how-do-i-click-a-button-by-hitting-enter-whilst-textbox-has-focus

Comment: You should be looking to set the *default action* (and cancel action) on your form rather than *manually implementing this*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# How do I click a button by hitting Enter whilst textbox has focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299086/c-sharp-how-do-i-click-a-button-by-hitting-enter-whilst-textbox-has-focus)

Comment: Set the form's AcceptButton property.  And perhaps you want to set the CancelButton property as well so that the Escape key works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 'AcceptButton' property of the Form. Assign the required button to the 'AcceptButton' property of the Form as shown below

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   AcceptButton = this.uiLoginButton;
}
```

No need to write 'KeyDown' event. You can delete your 'uiPasswordTextBox_KeyDown' event

Answer (score 0):

You can change your source code to the following:

Instead of

```
uiLoginButton.PerformClick();
```

simply use

```
uiLoginButton_Click(null, null);
```

This calls the method `uiLoginButton_Click` without any Parameters and because you don't rely in them this will work as a normal function call.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from just manually calling the click method, just create a third method that holds all the logic in your uiLoginButton_Click() method, and just make uiLoginButton_Click() a single line of code that calls said method.

Then just turn the uiLoginButton.PerformClick() method into that one as well.

Manually firing subscribed event methods is poor design.